# Repeatedly allocate memory without freeing it

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

The following code shows an example that repeatedly allocates memory without first calling `free`. Instead, it frees `**sign` after the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float ** fun(int nloc)
{
    float **sign;
    int i,nt=100,it,k;
    sign=(float **)calloc(nloc,sizeof(float *));
    for (i=0;i<nloc;i++)
        sign[i] = (float *)calloc(nt,sizeof(float *));

    for (it=0;it<nt;it++){
        for (k=0;k<nloc;k++){
            sign[k][it]=it*0.2;
        }
    }
    return sign;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i,isrc,n=3,nloc=1;
    float **sign=NULL;
    for (isrc=0;isrc<n;isrc++){
        sign = fun(nloc);
    }
    for (i=0;i<nloc;i++){
        free(sign[i]);
    }
    free(sign);
    exit(0);
}
```

This is a correct code snippet. My question is: why is it legal that we can allocate memory for a pointer in each iteration without having to free it first?

[Supplementary message]:

Hi all, I think there's one case we cannot `free` memory in the loop. If `buffer=p` and `p` is defined outside the loop, like:

```
float *buffer, *p;
/* Elements of p calculated */
for (...){
    /* allocate memory for **buffer */    
    buffer = p;
    free(buffer)
    /* if free here will cause p lost */
}
```

If free `buffer` at the end of each loop, it may cause `p` lost because `buffer` and `p` share the same memory address.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `sign` and `sign[0], sign[1], etc.`?

Comment: Aren’t they nloc different pointers?

Comment: The code has a memory leak (which is to say that it calls `calloc` more times than it calls `free`). The compiler does not warn you about this because it's extremely difficult, if not impossible, for a compiler to detect such problems. However, there are tools (e.g. [valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/valgrind/info)) that *will* detect memory leaks at run time.

Comment: One reason:  sometimes you *want* to be able to allocate more memory without freeing the previous memory first (e.g. if you were constructing a linked list, you wouldn't want the compiler to force you to free the first node in the list, just because you've now gone on to create the second node in the list)

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`,  1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful. 2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: this: `for (isrc=0;isrc<n;isrc++){
        sign = fun(nloc);
    }` overlays the pointer(s) on each iteration,  The result is the pointer to the prior allocated memory is lost (a unrecoverable memory leak)

Comment: when the parameters to `main()` are not going to be used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: `sign[k][it]=it*0.2;`  the literal: `0.2` is a `double`  strongly suggest using: `sign[k][it]=it*0.2f;`  Note the trailing `f` that makes the literal into a `float`

Comment: regarding: `This is a correct code snippet.`  No, it is not.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings

Comment: I found an exception. Could you please see my [Supplementary message] and make some comments about this? thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> why is it legal that we can allocate memory for a pointer in each iteration without having to free it first?

The responsibility of freeing dynamically allocated memory is left on the programmer. It is legal because the compiler does not enforce it, although there are code checking tools that can flag this problem.

Freeing dynamically allocated memory should be done in the reverse order of allocation. For ex:

```
for (i=0;i<nloc;i++)
    free(sign[i]);

free(sign);
```

Comment: Hi Sandy, I found an exception. Could you please see my [Supplementary message] and make some comments about this? thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is legal because in C, you as the programmer are responsible for memory management. There is a very good reason for this. To quote [another thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113177/why-do-languages-such-as-c-and-c-not-have-garbage-collection-while-java-does)

> Garbage collection requires data structures for tracking allocations
>   and/or reference counting. These create overhead in memory,
>   performance, and the complexity of the language. C++ is designed to be
>   "close to the metal", in other words, it takes the higher performance
>   side of the tradeoff vs convenience features. Other languages make
>   that tradeoff differently. This is one of the considerations in
>   choosing a language, which emphasis you prefer.

Not only is performance and code size a consideration, but different systems have difference addressing schemes for memory. It is also for this reason that C is easy to port and maintain across platforms, given that there is no garbage collection to alter.

EDIT: Some answers mention freeing memory space as opposed to the pointer itself, it is worth further specifying what that means: free() simply marks the allocated space as available, it is not 'freed' or erased, nor does any other operation occur on that memory space. It is then still incumbent on the programmer to delete the address that was assigned to the pointer variable.

Comment: I found an exception. Could you please see my [Supplementary message] and make some comments about this? thanks.

Comment: Hi @coco I can't seem to see your message. Happy to contribute some more information if you require assistance.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is: why is it legal that we can allocate memory for a pointer in each iteration without having to free it first?

**Short answer**

C trades away safety to gain simplicity and performance.

**Longer answer**

You don't free the *pointer*. You free the memory block the pointer is *pointing* at.

Think about what `malloc` (and `calloc`) does. They both allocate a piece of memory, and if the allocation is successful they return a pointer to that memory block. The allocation functions (like all functions) has no insight, nor control whatsoever of what you do with the return value. The functions does not even see the pointer that you are assigning the return value to.

It would be fairly complex (relatively speaking, C has a pretty simple structure) to implement a protection against it. First, consider this code:

```
int * a = malloc(1);
int * b = a;
a = malloc(1);
free(b);
free(a);
```

This code has no memory leaks, even though we did the precise thing you asked about. We reassigned `a` before calling free upon the memory from the first malloc. It works fine, because we have saved the address in `b`.

So in order to disallow reassigning pointers that points to a memory block *that no other pointer points at*, the runtime environment would need to keep track of this, and it is not entirely trivial. And it would also need to create extra code to handle all this. Since this check needs to be done at runtime, it may affect performance.

Also, remember that even though C may seem very low level today, it was considered a high level language when it came.

Comment: I found an exception. Could you please see my [Supplementary message] and make some comments about this? thanks.

Comment: @coco You cannot free the same allocation twice.